# Cannot drag draggable DIV from panel in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I've created some simple example with ExtJS drag-b-drop, it available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqqkc/2/).
And there is some issue - I cannot drag draggable divs from side panel (or region) - draggable div stays under the center region. Is that a bug in Ext or something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done in hacking way. It looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqqkc/4/)

In short, I appending element to document `body` tag - and dragged element displayed fine.